# React Native Gifted Chat attach multiple images

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I am using React Native Gifted Chat for one of my project. I am aware that there is a **image** option available where I can attach a single image to a chat. But, is there a way I can attach multiple images to a single chat?

Comment: any update on above?

Answer (score 0):

from documentation, the type of image is a string. so it's meant to attach one image. but a simple solution is to do like image:"img1,img2,.." , then use

```
renderMessageImage={(props)=> customMessageImages(props)}
```

where

```
customMessageImages=(props:MessageImageProps<IMessage>)=>{
   const imgs = props.image.split(',')
   return(
      {
         imgs.map(img=>(
            <Image source={img} />
         ))
       }
   )
}
```